# multiple select drop down dependent on another drop down option value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to have validation as dependent to each other with 3 select box options value example: if we select man 14 then remain 16 should be show in teenager and child after then i select 6 people in teenager then remain 10 people should be show in child option then child can be select only 10 they cant be more then people limit. see below image

```
$total_booked_people_limit = "30"; 
<div class="form-group" >
    <label for="sel1"><b>Adults (18+):</b></label>
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <?php for($i=0;  $i<=$total_booked_people_limit; $i++){                                
            echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
        } ?>
    </select>

    <label for="sel1"><b>Teenager(14 - 17):</b></label>
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <?php for($j=0;  $j<=$total_booked_people_limit; $j++) {                                   
            echo "<option value=\"$j\">$j</option>";
        } ?>
    </select>

    <label for="sel1"><b>Children (7 - 14):</b></label>
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
        <?php for($k=0;  $k<=$total_booked_people_limit; $k++) {                                   
            echo "<option value=\"$k\">$k</option>";
        } ?>
    </select>
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php $total_booked_people_limit = "30"; ?>
<div class="form-group" >
    <label for="sel1"><b>Adults (18+):</b></label>
    <select class="form-control first" id="sel1">
        <?php for($i=0;  $i<=$total_booked_people_limit; $i++) {                                
            echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
        } ?>
    </select>

    <label for="sel1"><b>Teenager(14 - 17):</b></label>
    <select class="form-control second" id="sel1">
        <?php for($j=0;  $j<=$total_booked_people_limit; $j++) {                                
            echo "<option value=\"$j\">$j</option>";
        } ?>
    </select>

    <label for="sel1"><b>Children (7 - 14):</b></label>
    <select class="form-control third" id="sel1">
        <?php for($k=0;  $k<=$total_booked_people_limit; $k++) {                                
            echo "<option value=\"$k\">$k</option>";
        } ?>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".first").change(function() {
                var first = $(".first").val();
                var remaining = 30-first;
                $('.second').children('option').remove();
                for(firstcount = 0; firstcount <= remaining; firstcount++){
                    $(".second").append("<option>"+firstcount+"</option>");
                }
            });

            $(".second").change(function() {
                var first = $(".first").val();
                var second = $(".second").val();
                var firstsecond = +first + +second;
                var remaining = 30-firstsecond;
                $('.third').children('option').remove();
                for(secondcount = 0; secondcount <= remaining; secondcount++){
                    $(".third").append("<option>"+secondcount+"</option>");
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: This is ok ! but there are we have to select row wise first have to select Adult then teenager then child ,

Comment: If we will select as per our wish then its not working like user want to select first child then adult then teenager same as like user can select any one , it should not be order wise .

Comment: You can see by this link https://beiceland.is/akureyri-classic-whale-watching bottom right corner .